# Determining lake catchment in Arc Hydro tools?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arc-hydro

I am trying to determine a lake's catchment with Arc Hydro tools or other tools in ArcMap.

I tried basin tools in sptial analyst and catchment grid delineation tools in ArcHydro Tools but all the time I got too large areas along the watercourses where there are many lakes. I need the catchment of individual lakes. How to do it?

Comment: Wouldn't it be exactly the same method for a lake as for a river? In both cases water flows downhill.

Comment: What procedures have you tried already and how did their output fail to meet your needs/expectations?

Comment: I tried basin tools in sptial analyst and catchment grid delineation tools in ArcHydro Tools but all the time I got too large areas along the watercourses where there are many lakes. I need the catchment of individual lakes.

Comment: what makes you think the areas are too large?

Comment: there are several lakes in them that are not connected to each other. I have to separate their basins.

Comment: Set areas under lake to no data.